# how to load data from an external database into an iPhone app

Tags: swift

Basically what I want to do I be able to enter in data on a website, and have it appear on an iPhone app, so I want it to send the data to my iPhone, and store it so that every time i open the app, it will re load the data and put it on the screen. How can I go about this?

Comment: You question is too general and we are not able to help that way. Welcome to SO anyway.

Comment: What exactly you want to to do ? Do you want just to show the content of a website on the iPhone or do you want to read some XML-File from a website and show it on your iPhone OR ... OR ... OR ... there are a lot of things, that you could mean! As Lucas said, the question is to general to give a specific answer. :))

Comment: There are thousands of ways to go about this, but generally speaking you will need your iOS application to talk to a web service. The easiest barrier to entry is using a service like Parse.com which will provide you a drop-in SDK and database on the cloud. They have great tutorials and sample applications that show you how to do read data stored on their service and reload said data in a table view in your iOS application. You could also get very custom in creating a web service of your own and sharing an api.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a backend-side to your app. If you don't have any experience with backend-developing, I would recommend taking a look at Parse.com or other similar backend providers. They give you a server-solution without having to develop it yourself.

Good luck, and welcome to SO!